# Use Simpson's compound rule with $n= 4,6,8… $, until successive approximations of the following integrals agree to an accuracy of $10^{−6}$

Tags: real-analysis

can you guide me in the solution for this exercise?
Use Simpson's compound rule with $n= 4,6,8… $, until successive approximations of the following integrals agree to an accuracy of $10^{−6}$ . Determine the number of nodes that are required. Using the adaptive quadrature algorithm, approximate the integral with an accuracy of $10^{−6}$ and count the number of nodes. Did adaptive quadrature produce any improvement?

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}sen \ x^2 dx$

What do I have to do so that the successive approximations of the following integrals agree with an accuracy of $10^{−6}$ . Determine the number of nodes required? Using the adaptive quadrature algorithm, approximate the integral.
can you explain to me? I can't find the way to advance in this exercise, should I solve the integral with $n=4$, then calculate again with $n= 6$ and so on?

Comment: That seems to be what the question is asking you to do. A program or spreadsheet would be useful.

Comment: Hello, what program can I use? I am very confused because I don't know what to do to determine the number of nodes that are required to match the approximation with what the exercise asks for

Comment: You just keep trying it with more and more nodes until the last two calculations agree to the specified accuracy.  That gets you one answer for the number of nodes required.  Your nodes will be evenly spaced over the interval.  The rule is exact for polynomials up through third degree, so the error is proportional to the fourth derivative of the function.

Comment: Then you use "the adaptive quadrature" which must be a routine you are given or had to program.  It will put more nodes where the fourth derivative of the function is highest.  You will probably find that it gets the specified accuracy with fewer nodes.

Comment: You were given two methods to calculate an integral. Just do what you were asked to do, it seems very clear. Using a spreadsheet might be good enough for the calculations, otherwise you might have to write a computer program.

Comment: Just saying: I don't like the first method _at all_. You will evaluate f(x) at completely different points, so the results for say n = 104 and n = 106 might be very, very close together by sheer coincidence, but far away from the exact integral.

Comment: should I compute the error for each? first for $ n = 4$, then $6$